# dependant: :destroy leading to postgresql error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgresql-9.3

```
class Accdist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accdistlavoraziones, dependent: :destroy
```

When deleting an accdist, the following is being output by the console:

```
 Accdist Load (27.3ms)  SELECT "accdists".* FROM "accdists" WHERE "accdists"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
 Accdistlavorazione Load (20.2ms)  SELECT "accdistlavoraziones".* FROM "accdistlavoraziones" WHERE "accdistlavoraziones"."accdist_id" = 1
  SQL (59.7ms)  DELETE FROM "accdistlavoraziones" WHERE "accdistlavoraziones"."" = $1  [[nil, nil]]
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: ...OM "accdistlavoraziones" WHERE "accdistlavoraziones"."" = $1
                                                                ^
: DELETE FROM "accdistlavoraziones" WHERE "accdistlavoraziones"."" = $1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 155.3ms
```

The oddity is that if I query:

```
Accdistlavorazione.where('accdist_id = ?', 1).count
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "accdistlavoraziones" WHERE (accdist_id = 1)
 => 10
```

Valid results are being returned.

Why is the internal mechanism resulting in postgresql handling nil (s) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone coming across this, what probably occurred is the following.
- create a join table via the rails shortcut `has_and_belongs_to_many`
- realise that you need later a `has_many ... through:` set-up
- chug along creating new join records actually runs... because the `[...]_id` is being referenced.
– come delete time, you're looking for an id of the join table and naturally that is `nil`

Comment: Thank you! I added a primary_key to the join table and it fixed the problem: `add_column :join_table_name, :id, :primary_key` (in a migration)